# Django behind reverse proxy ?next= issue

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have deployed a Django application behind an nginx reverse proxy.  This proxy handles multiple Django applications

So the main url is for example https://www.example.com

and then I use the reverse proxy to redirect to the specific Django application using subdirectory

for example https://www.example.com/myapp

The problem is that if I logout from myapp and try to access a page that requires login the redirect link is wrong, instead of

https://www.example.com/myapp?next=/mainpage

it gives me

https://www.example.com/?next=/myapp/mainpage

which is wrong since "myapp" cannot listen to requests from https://www.example.com/

Is there any way I can force Django to understand that the default url is https://www.example.com/myapp and not https://www.example.com?

Thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am facing the same problem!